# Create a multithreaded program by creating a subclass of Thread and then creating, initializing, and starting two Thread objects from main class.

Tags: java, multithreading

Create a multithreaded program by creating a subclass of Thread and then creating, initializing, and starting two Thread objects from main class. The threads will execute the following output in the suitable interface.

**OUTPUT : 
 
thread1: Java

thread1: is

thread2: Java

thread1: an

thread2: is

thread1: exciting

thread2: an

thread1: new

thread2: exciting

thread1: language

thread1: for

thread1: concurrent

thread2: new

thread1: programming.

thread2: language

thread2: for

thread2: concurrent

thread2: programming.**

this is my coding  is seem to call thread 1 first then thread 2. How to make it display like that output.

```
class Thread1 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread1: Java");
        System.out.println("Thread1: is ");
        System.out.println("Thread1: exciting ");
        System.out.println("Thread1: new ");
        System.out.println("Thread1: language ");
        System.out.println("Thread1: for ");
        System.out.println("Thread1: concurrent ");
        System.out.println("Thread1: programming ");

    }
}

class Thread2 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread2 Java");
        System.out.println("Thread2: an ");
        System.out.println("Thread2: is ");
        System.out.println("Thread2: an ");
        System.out.println("Thread2: exciting");
        System.out.println("Thread2: new");
        System.out.println("Thread2: language");
        System.out.println("Thread2: for");
        System.out.println("Thread2: concurrent");
        System.out.println("Thread2: programming");
        suspend();
    }
}
class Thread3 extends Thread
{
public void run()
{
System.out.print("Thread3");
try
        {
sleep(1000);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}

System.out.print(" Running");
}
}

class ThreadDemo3
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
{
Thread1 obj1 = new Thread1();
obj1.start();
Thread2 obj2 = new Thread2();
obj2.start();

}
}
```

Comment: There's no question here, and also don't do that, subclass `Runnable` and submit to a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: You should edit your output to the question, the comments area is not the right place for that.

Comment: No dispute that Java is a `language`. Possibly even `exciting`. `for concurrent programming`, ok. But `new`?

Answer (score 1):

Execute it until you get the desired result.

No seriously, this a typical example to show that threads do **NOT** execute in a specific order.

So the output of your program should be different each time you run it (not predictable). But you try to do exactly that.

One solution could be to use a lock (see [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)) that you acquire and release it when the other thread should do the job (remember to add some kind of wait to prevent the thread from instant reacquiring the lock), but this is counter productive here.

By the way: this looks for me like you copied your homework to SO.

**Edit**:  Get an older Machine, where the first Thread is not yet finished when the new Thread starts.

Really, **predicting** the order in which the commands are executed is like playing roulette. You can try it, but at the end you will loose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no non-messy way to do this madness.  If I was forced to do it at gunpoint, I would probably have each thread run a switch/case state-machine and, when a thread-swapover is required, signal a semaphore to the other thread and wait on another semaphore for its state-machine to signal back.